# Why does it stop even though I used continue?

Tags: c, while-loop, conditional-statements, continue

Basic coding with while loop and conditional statements. However I've encountered a problem where I'm oblivious to where the fault is at.

So what happens here is that the code will ask the user to input the starting and the ending point for 'loading' and it will do it's thing. The catch is that the code should exclude numbers divisible by 4 in between the start and the end integers.

But in my case, the loop suddenly stops at 3 even though I used 'continue;' in my if statement just below the 'while' line, how should I fix this?
['output'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbgEY.jpg)

Anyways, here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int start, end;

printf("Enter the starting point: ");
scanf("%d", &start);
printf("Enter the ending point: ");
scanf("%d", &end);

while(start <= end){
    if(start % 4 == 0){
        continue;
    }
    printf("Loading...%d%\n", start);

    start++;
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Please hard-code the "input" (the values of `start` and `end`) and use a debugger to step through the code to see what really happens.

Comment: Your loop doesn't stop, it actually runs infinitely because when start == 4 then you will stay (continue) in the while loop, hence never reaching start++;

Comment: @RedaMeskali oh I see what you mean, how should I fix it? When I removed the conditional statement, it ran smoothly but with it in it, it runs infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(start <= end){
    if(start % 4 != 0){
        printf("Loading...%d%\n", start);
    }
    start++;
}
```

Here is a suggestion which does involve continue.

Comment: Oh it worked! Thanks a lot!

but I just want to know, was the 'continue;' the error and if so why?

Comment: Just go through your code when start == 4 and see what happens

Comment: @OverHeaven Think about when and where you want to increment `start`... Perhaps a `for` loop would have been better?

Answer (score 1):

`continue` keyword doesn't have any problem. The thing is your `start` variable doesn't increment when continue executed. You can use `continue` like this. So that, the start variable is incremented before it continues.

```
if(start % 4 == 0){
    start++;
    continue;
}
```

One more thing to add. `printf("Loading...%d%\n", start);` this line should get some warning. because on `printf()`, `%` has a special meaning to format variable. So you should use `printf("Loading...%d%%\n", start);` to get rid of that warning.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind, thank you so much!